# How to detect RAID on Linux?

Tags: linux

I have the Linux server Ubuntu 11.10, and previous administrator assure me, that the RAID 1 (software) is used on the system. However, when I do `fdisk -l` one of the (two) disks even does not have partition table.

```
 cat /proc/mdstat

       Personalities :
       unused devices: <none>
```

I believe that RAID are NOT configured and second disk do nothing.
How do I know for sure that I'm right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming it is not Soft RAID, do you know which RAID card you are using? e.g., HP　Smart Array P400.

One reliable way to check in command line is to run a disk array command line tool.

E.g.: for HP disk array configuration, you can install `hpacucli` and run:

```
hpacucli ctrl all show config
```

Output could look like:

```
Smart Array P400 in Slot 0    ()

   array A (SAS, Unused Space: 0 MB)

      logicaldrive 1 (136.7 GB, RAID 1+0, OK)

      physicaldrive 1I:1:1 (port 1I:box 1:bay 1, SAS, 146 GB, OK)
      physicaldrive 1I:1:2 (port 1I:box 1:bay 2, SAS, 146 GB, OK)
```

And you can easily figure out the truth.

Comment: No, it was assumed that a software raid.

Comment: Thanks for advice, now I'm sure - my colleague thought wrong.

Comment: "md" devices does not exist and mdadm not even installed.

Answer (score 0):

Check logs or dmesg to see if there is any mention of a software RAID. You could also use mount to see which devices are mounted.

*Also, you should have posted this on superuser.com or serverfault.com as it has nothing to do with programming.*